# can't insert event starting on a defined date into fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, unix-timestamp, mktime, gcal

I'm working on a codeIgniter project.I use fullCalendar to insert events. The concept that I want to implement is similar to google Calendar. When a user clicks on a day in the calendar, he inserts an event starting on the date of the clicked day. 
I did an ajax call from my view and post the date to the controller.Once in the controller, all what I want to do is to set the start date with this value and to insert the event in the calendar. Here is my code (controller)

```
function add_event()
    {

           $click_date = $this->input->post('date'); 
           $date= explode(" ", "$click_date ");
           $month= (int)$date[1];
           $day= (int)$date[2];
           $year= (int)$date[3]; 
           $date_start = $this->unix_timestamp($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
           $this->load->library('gcal');
           $date_end = $this->unix_timestamp('2012-08-15'); 

           $params = array(
            'calendarId'    => 'my Google calendar id',
            'allday'        => true, 
            'start'         => $date_start,
            'end'       => $date_end,
            'summary'       => 'event',
            'description'   => "My first event"
        );

        $response = $this->gcal->eventInsert($params); 


        if($response)
        {
            echo "true";
        } 
    }
```

Here is my unix_timestamp function :

```
function unix_timestamp($date)
    {
        $date = str_replace(array(' ', ':'), '-', $date);
        $c    = explode('-', $date);
        $c    = array_pad($c, 6, 0);
        array_walk($c, 'intval');

        return mktime($c[3], $c[4], $c[5], $c[1], $c[2], $c[0]);
    }
```

On the calendar, the event is inserted but not on the right starting date. It starts on 2012-01-01 which is the default date I guess. I don't understand why my starting date isn't set correctly.
What I am doing wrong? Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I should convert the fullCalendar date format into string before posting it to the controller. One line was missing :

```
date_format = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`
```

Hope that it would help people who have the same problem
`